# I am having White label error (403 forbidden) when trying to test h2 connection

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, pom.xml, h2

I am trying to set up an h2 configuration process.
I have added the following code to my `application.properties` file in the resources folder but when I launch `localhost:8080/h2-console` it does now show my URL configured in the `application.properties` file.

It shows another URL `localhost:8080/-test and` even when I click test connection, it displays a white label `403 forbidden error`.

The code used to configure h2 in the application.properties file is

```
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.datasource.platform=h2
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:mojec
spring.datasource.username=sa
```

This is my pom.xml file

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.9.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.mojec</groupId>
    <artifactId>eWallet</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>eWallet</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
```

Comment: you have this properties `spring.h2.console.path=/h2-console` ?

Comment: No I don't but when I start the application and put localhost:8080/h2-console in the browser it navigates to the h2 test connection and connect page but it shows a different url from the one I put in my application properties file.

Comment: Have you enabled spring security?

Comment: Yes I have enabled spring security

Comment: Was this ever solved?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue, after adding the dev tools for spring boot the issue is resolved, just add the below dependency in your pom.xml above of com.h2database.

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
 </dependency>
```